# React Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to deploy my react application on my Cloud Web server. But I get the message "Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined".

Here is my code:

```
//App.js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './bootstrap.min.css';
import Listitems from './Listitems.js';
import Cart from './Cart.js';
import Products from './Products.json'


class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            inCart:[],
            ref:[],
            revenue:0
        }
    }

handler(obj, ref) {
    this.setState({
      inCart: obj,
      ref:ref
    });
    var x;
    var revenue = [];
    const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;  
    for(x in obj){
        revenue.push(obj[x].price * obj[x].quantity)
    }
    if(revenue.length !== 0) {
        this.setState({revenue:revenue.reduce(reducer)})
    } else {
        this.setState({revenue:0})
    }
}
render(){
    var x;
    var cartLength = 0;
    for(x in this.state.inCart){
        cartLength += this.state.inCart[x].quantity
    }
    return (
        <div className="App " >
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light shadow w-100">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="www.google.fr" >Mon projet panier</a>
                    <div>Panier <span data-v-d39b0b74="" className="badge badge-success">{cartLength}</span></div>
                </nav>
                <div id="mdm-cart" className="container">
                    <h1 className="title border-bottom mb-5 display-1">Mon panier</h1>
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="basket col-md-8">
                                <Cart  viewCart={this.state.viewCart} handler={this.handler} reference={this.state.ref} inCart={this.state.inCart} revenue={this.state.revenue}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="liste col-md-4">
                                <h2>Produits en relation :</h2>
                                <Listitems key={Products.id} data={Products} handler={this.handler} reference={this.state.ref} inCart={this.state.inCart}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  );
}   
}

export default App;
```

I've also tried to use other import method like :

```
const { React } = require('react');
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Here is the error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
at Module.<anonymous> (App.js:15)
at l ((index):1)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.e870a004.chunk.js:1)
at l ((index):1)
at a ((index):1)
at Array.e ((index):1)
at main.e870a004.chunk.js:1
```

Edit : Add Package.json file

```
{
 "name": "Mon projet panier",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
   "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
   "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
   "customize-cra": "^0.9.1",
   "react": "^16.12.0",
   "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.5",
   "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
   "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
   "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
 },
 "browserslist": {
   "production": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version"
   ]
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/cli": "^7.7.7",
   "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7"
 }
}
```

One thing that is odd is that the error is located in App:15 but the code need to know what is React.Component in order to go there.

If anyone have any clue, I'll appreciate !

Comment: Please, share your package.json

Comment: @Julian have you use React.Component without importing... import React from 'react'; in that component?

Comment: @Héctor I made an edit to add the package json

Comment: @VahidAkhtar Yes the import is made in the first line in App.js file. It work perfectly locally

Comment: How do you deploy it to cloud?

Comment: Did you use typescript your project?

Comment: @MiroslavPapirnik I'm using Ovhcloud.

- I run a build from "npm run build"
- Transfert the file from my computer to the server by using filezilla
- Then I go on the server configuration on ovh and restart it

Comment: The problem is with how you deploy and not with react

Comment: @PrakashT No I didn't use it

Comment: So after "npm run build" do you copy content of build folder or what files?

Comment: @DennisVash Would you happen to know why exactly ? Is it transfering file from filezilla ?

Comment: It might also be helpful if you could specify which is App.js line number 15

Comment: You should ask a new question where you explaining how you deploy your project and ask "How to deploy to X cloud server"

Comment: @MiroslavPapirnik Yes indeed. I copy everything generated in my local build folder into the public folder in my server, which is the specified folder for the serveur to get static files.

Comment: @gprathour Sorry about that, I didn't see the line wheren't specified.

Line 15 in App.js is just after the function App in the state ref:[]

Comment: I think it is deploy issue too. It looks like React library is not linked and in production build all component names should be shorten. Is your project in public repo? I can take look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Component of undefined means that its parent which is React is undefined, so either your server environment doesn't support React build pack or take a look at the build script webpack configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `import React, { Component } from 'react';`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

The files and folders were mixed up serveur side, App.js was in the wrong place. The server didn't even start at all because of this. The error made me think that the server started but were stopped because of the import React.

Anyway, I reoganized the server's folder and restart the server. And it works.

Thanks for you help !